# Laravel frontend website logo showing problem. New logo isn't replacing previous logo

Tags: laravel

Logo is showing every times I uploaded a new logo. New logo isn't replacing previous logo.
Here it should look like.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQpQ8.jpg

But it's showing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BycVa.png

This is **index.blade.php** code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzk4U.jpg

This is **Controller File**

class LogoController extends Controller
{
//

```
public function index()
{
    $logos = logo::all();
    return view('front.index', compact('logos'));
}

public function create()
{
    $logos = logo::all();
    return view('backend.addlogo');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $logo = new logo;
    if ($request->hasFile('logo')) 
    {   
        
        $file = $request->file('logo');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move('uploads/logo/', $filename);
        $logo->logo = $filename;
    }
    $logo->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Logo added successfully');
}
```

Please help me resolve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show the controller codes which is used to render the index page? You showed here, logoController codes, which only upload and store logo file. but after uploading logo file, you will have make relation with other model / settings .

Comment: Here is web.php file https://imgur.com/bCRigaD                                                                  Here is Model file https://imgur.com/MznwThG

Comment: Please don't post your code as images. **Code is text**, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71336319/edit) and copy, paste and format your code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the old logo is stored on your CSS file, try to find the image url in CSS file, if you dont find it, try to use leftCtrl+LeftClick in your refresh icon on your website, it will reload all CSS and everything so its showed up.